# How to clean the commets table SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with IDS and COMMENTS, in which people chose on a website the reason why they ended their subscription, and that data is sent to a table.

The persons can choose more reasons, but all the reasons are sent into a single row like:

```
id = 111 comments = I don't like the productI hate youNever expected this
```

Can I rearange this table to receive the following?

```
id= 111 / comments= I don't like the product
id= 111 / comments= I hate you
id= 11 / comments= Never expected this
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Only if you can guarantee a seperator or seperators that will always denote a beginning or an end of a single statement. Initially it looks like a Capital letter may be that, but I would guess you cannot guarantee people would use a capital letter, In my experience they dont even use one on their own names most of the time

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly, there are premade answers from witch they can choose and they all start with a capital letter, I will do some research to see how can I separete them in diffrents raws.

Comment: is it a SQL question? which DB do you use? MySQL or Snowflake?

Comment: @GokhanAtil Snowflake

Comment: So do you need a SQL to parse the string? or do you need to parse it outside of the database (like RiggsFolly showed)?

Answer (score 0):

Then this may get you to where you want

```
$in= "I don't like the productI hate youNever expected this";
$str = preg_replace("([A-Z])", "££$0", $in);
$arr = explode("££",trim($str, '££'));
print_r($arr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => I don't like the product
    [1] => I hate you
    [2] => Never expected this
)
```